# Join column names from Tab1 with 1 column values of Tab2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with the following structures:

```
// tab1:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
|----|------|------|------|------|
| 1  | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val4 |
| 2  | Val5 | Val6 | Val7 | Val8 |

// tab2:

| Name |
|------|
| Col1 |
| Col3 |
```

I now need to get all values from `tab1` and somehow join them with the values of the column of `tab2`, so that in the frontend all columns from `tab1`, that are also present in `tab2`, are bold.

In pseudocode it would look like that:

```
SELECT Col1, COl2, Col3, Col4 FROM tab1, tab2 WHERE ID=1 AND {possibly a left join on tab2}
```

The desired output as a table in the fronted could be:

Value 1: **Val1**
Value 2: Val2
Value 3: **Val3**
Value 4: Val4

Since `col1` and `col3` are also in `tab2`, their values should be bold.
So I just need the appropriate query with a "flag". In the frontend I then would just loop the results and look for the flag. If the flag is set, display the value as bold.

*I don't really have influence on the database structure.*

Comment: what is the join condition of the two tables?

Comment: Does the `tab1` have table fixed number of `colN` columns? i mean (col1,col2,col3 and col4)? And how do you relate these two tables?

Comment: @DylanSu: There is no actual join condition. It just should check if the columns from `tab1` are also present in `tab2`.

Comment: @1000111: No, there is no fixed column width. They are not really related.

Comment: The above tab2 structure is complete? tab2 has only one column? If it is, you don't have a chance to perform JOIN. Besides, what happen if a row in tab1 was/is/will be deleted?

Comment: @fusion3k: Yes, the structure is complete.

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Comment: @Strawberry: What could be a possible solution?

Comment: e.g. `id, type, val`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table structure is complete and we know all the column names, we can execute the below query to check whether a value exists or not.

```
select col1 as col1 , 
 (select count(*) from tab2 where name = 'col1') col1_exists,
 col2 as col2, 
 (select count(*) from tab2 where name = 'col2') col2_exists,
 col3 as col3 , 
 (select count(*) from tab2 where name = 'col1') col3_exists
 from tab1;
```

For non zero 'exists' values, we can show the corresponding column value in bold. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98fb00/4/0).

Comment: Thank you. But the user needs to define the table, he wants to get the values from. So `tab1` can differ and we don't know all the column names.

Comment: In that case, we can leave column names as '?' in the actual query and then, replace at runtime depending on table structure..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
t.`VALUE`,
(CASE WHEN tab2.Name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) flag
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    Col1 AS `VALUE`,
    'Col1' AS colNum
    FROM tab1 
    WHERE ID = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    Col2 AS `VALUE`,
    'Col2' AS colNum
    FROM tab1 
    WHERE ID = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    Col3 AS `VALUE`,
    'Col3' AS colNum
    FROM tab1 
    WHERE ID = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    Col4 AS `VALUE`,
    'Col4' AS colNum
    FROM tab1 
    WHERE ID = 1

) t
LEFT JOIN tab2 
ON tab2.`Name` = t.colNum;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fea3/1/0)

Comment: Thank you. But the user needs to define the table, he wants to get the values from. So `tab1` can differ and we don't know all the column names.

Comment: Then I would definitely say that a very bad design where you don't know the column names even! Either change your design or pay for it. Sorry to say dude.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the restrictions with your design, you are not able to do this with MYSQL alone, but you can with the help of PHP:

1. get the column names from tbl2
2. use those column names to obtain your results from tbl1

Try the following (assuming you use `mysqli`):

```
//get columns from tbl2
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl2';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$cols = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cols[] = $row['name'];
}

//get results from tbl1 using column names
$sql = 'SELECT ' . implode(',', $cols) . ' FROM tbl1 WHERE ID=1';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```